# Different outputs in GHCI

Tags: haskell

Running this with `M 1` will show a new line and `a` will show the characters "\n" in the ghci output.
Since they are the same characters i would expect the same behaviour.

Any reason why?

```
data V = M Int
instance Show V where
  show m = a

a :: [Char]
a = "\n"
```

Comment: If you define `instance Show V` as `show m = show a` you'll get the same behaviour.

Comment: Yes that was my problem with this. That it adds a show to the function but i didn't see anywhere specified.

I didn't find anything related to this so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever a value is displayed in GHCi, it uses the `Show` instance of that object to convert it to human-readable text by applying the `show` function, then printing the resulting `String`. In your case, what is happening is:

- You have defined the `Show` instance of `V` to be a constant `"\n"`, or newline. Thus when GHCi tries to display a value of type `V` it outputs a newline.
- By contrast, the `Show` instance of `String` is defined in such a way that for any string `s`, `show s` will output the Haskell representation of `s`. For instance, `show "\n"` will give a result of `"\"\\n\"` (i.e. quotation mark, backslash, `n`, quotation mark). (Try running `show "myString"` in GHCi and seeing the result for different strings to get an idea of how this works.) Thus when GHCi displays a `String`, it takes the string (a newline, in your case), converts it to a human-readable format with escape characters using `show`, and then displays that new string.

Why is `show` implemented in this convoluted way for strings? I’m not quite sure, but one possibility is disambiguation: `show 1` is `"1"`, but `show "1"` is `"\"1\""`. When printed to the console, the former is clearly a number, whereas the latter is clearly a string.